# In Visual Studio 2022 accidentally renaming an event handler breaks the Form Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-2022

Usually, when you change an event name ( not in the properties window), it will come up with this error: [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uENgx.png)

However, when I upgraded to VS 2022, if I changed the event handler code ([changed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPvF0.png)) and then open my designer window, I'm greeted to this ([a broken designer window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPKWL.png)).

Even if I reverted the event handler name change, the window would stay the same. I just want the form to go back to how it looked with all my buttons, menu-strips, etc. ([What the window should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn8SY.png))

Please help this inexperienced coder ;(

Edit 1:
-Tried rebuilding, didn't fix the Designer window.
-Tried restarting VS after fix and it still didn't work.
-Didn't use refactor, but after correcting the name the designer window is still broken (yes I checked the designer file)
-It's too late to use ctrl-Z
-I also tried deleting the event from both Form1.Designer.cs and Form1.cs [Image of Form1.Designer.cs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD1Tr.png)

It's like it's not displaying Form1, The text used to be set to Form1, but after the error the Text is empty
([This is what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fkfu.png)). But the Design name is still Form1

Comment: After you fix the code, try rebuilding the project. That usually does it for me.

Comment: Did you use the refactor option to rename (right click, rename), or did you change the name of just the function?  Have you checked the designer file to make sure the event is correct there?

Comment: `CTRL-Z` then rebuild, go back. Doesn't work? Close the Form and reopen it. -- Or just rename the handler, `ALT+ENTER` -> auto-apply the change.

Comment: Edit the code-behind in the designer and make sure there is a click event that uses that name.

Comment: Restarting VS might also help in some cases.

Comment: If you removed the event handler subscription from the code in `.Designer.cs` and you still cannot see the Form's Designer, then you have more than one problem, you didn't just rename an event handler, you did something else.

Answer (score 0):

In order to rename the names of events, variables, methods, etc. use the keyboard shortcut ***Ctrl + R + R***.

All information about the controls located on your form (*instances, positions, colors, sizes, events, etc.*) is concentrated in the *InitializeComponent()* method in **.Designer.cs*. The fact that you have an empty form displayed means that your form is most likely using a different *Form1.Designer.cs*.

Go to the script of your form, find the constructor there:

```cs
...

public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}

...
```

Hold down the ***Ctrl*** key, hover over the name of the *InitializeComponent* method called in the constructor, and click the left mouse button. Visual Studio will take you to the place where the *InitializeComponent* method is described.

Check if there is information about those buttons that you showed in one of the images. Most likely, this information will not be there. If you still have the original *Form1.Designer.cs* in your project, you can simply copy its *InitializeComponent* method and replace this method in a newer designer's script.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.

After investigation of  `InitializeComponent()` I found that all the statements `this.Controls.Add(...)` were missing.

Re-adding them makes both the Form and the Designer work as before.
I have no clue why this happened, but it's nice to know there is an easy fix.

At least this taught me to always use the rename/refactor function of VS instead of the hacky way ;)